# Making a cell required based on combobox selection

Tags: ms-access, vba

Nw to the forum and may as well be new to programming.

I would like to make '***Invoice No.***' text box required, ONLY when '***INVOICED***' is selected in my combobox.

Answer (score 2):

If your form is bound, you could add the validation in the before update event like this:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.cboType = "INVOICED" And Nz(Me.InvoiceNo) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Invoice No. is required!", vbExclamation, Me.Caption
        Me.InvoiceNo.SetFocus
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

If unbound form, add the above statements (except `Cancel = True`) to your button click event.